# OwnCloud Missing after installation on ubuntu server

Tags: 14.04, server, webserver, owncloud-server, owncloud-client

I need some help with implementing a solution. 
I have installed owncloud on ubuntu server as shown over [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s3pryWdZyas)

However, when I type the below in my browser:

```
<myip_address>/owncloud
```

I get, a screen where it says:

```
The requested URL /owncloud was not found on this server.
Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at <myip_address> Port 80
```

However, when I type my `<myip_address>`, I am able to see the apache screen.
With some research I do understand that there is a [bug](https://github.com/owncloud/core/issues/6305.) with Ubuntu 13

However, I am not able to understand how to fix this. I am using `Ubuntu Server 14.04.5` on my `Ubuntu 16.04 LTS` via `ssh`.

I  did found a possible [solution](https://forum.owncloud.org/viewtopic.php?t=21050) or [as here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23923381/owncloud-not-available-after-installation-on-ubuntu-server-14-04), but I am not able to implement it.

**[Edit:] I have changed both the files i.e. `000-default.conf` and `default-ssl.conf` in the folder, but yet I see the same message in browser.**

Comment: What happens when you type `https://<ip address>/owncloud` ?

Comment: It says owncloud was not found. @nullmeta

Comment: Try following the official documentation [found here](https://doc.owncloud.org/server/latest/admin_manual/installation/)

Comment: Already did. Still The issue persists. @nullmeta

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are accessing the wrong path or it is installed in the wrong directory. Please look into the /var/www/html folder. 
By the way. Please use Nextcloud instead of Owncloud. Nextcloud is the successor project which is more secure and fully open source and has more features. A working tutorial how to install it can be found here. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-nextcloud-on-ubuntu-16-04